# How to install nodejs and node red together using a batch file in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, batch-file, cmd, node-red

I am trying to install Node.js and node-red on to a Windows system through a set of commands in a batch file. But the Node.js installation guide says " After installation completes, close any open command prompts and re-open to ensure new environment variables are picked up". To solve this problem i am using two different batch files.Is there a way to make both installation using a single batch file?

**a.bat**

```
:: Section 1: Nodejs Installation
    cd/
    cd package
    node-v12.13.0-x64.msi
    start b.bat
    PAUSE
```

**b.bat**

```
 :: Section 1: Node Red Installation
     start npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
```

Iam trying to install Node.js first and trying to start another batch file. But its not working. How else can i do this?

Comment: In my opinion, it is not necessary to close command prompts and reopen one to check if the environment variables have been set. What are you going to do if one of the variables isn't set, install the `.msi` again? And if so what would that achieve? _The likelihood is that it will fail again_.

Comment: Closing the command window works. I mean it sets the environmental variables.If i dont close the command window and try to install node-red using npm , its says "npm command not recognized".

Comment: @Compo the environment variables are set at a system level, the already running command prompt will not pick up the changes as it only reads the system environment variables when it's started.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you might not need the path, if you know npm has been installed, you can do it without closing. The files will exist in the relevant folders:

```
 :# Section 1: Nodejs Installation
    cd\
    cd package
    node-v12.13.0-x64.msi
 :# Section 2: Node Red Installation
    call "%programfiles%\nodejs\npm.cmd" install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
    pause
```

Alternatively you can search for it, but might take a little longer:

```
 :# Section 1: Nodejs Installation
    cd\
    cd package
    echo node-v12.13.0-x64.msi
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('where /r %systemdrive%\ npm.cmd') do set "locat=%%a" & goto section2
    :section2
 :# Section 2: Node Red Installation
    echo call "%locat%" install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
    pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea using just a single [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```bat
@If "%~1"=="" ("\package\node-v12.13.0-x64.msi"
    Start "" "%~f0" -installs
    Exit /B)
@Call npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-red
```

If you have other `npm` installations, just add them on the subsequent lines, remembering to prepend them with `Call`